# Clear a line faster than [0][d][$]

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a faster way to erase the text on a line than

- pressing <kbd>0</kbd> to jump to the start, then
- pressing <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> to delete until the end of the line?

Also, what if I wanted to delete everything *except* the indentation?  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As you said, there are multiple ways, and you can also take into account on what your next action will be after you clear or delete the current line.

1. <kbd>dd</kbd> will delete the current line (not clear)
2. <kbd>0D</kbd> will clear the current line including whitespace
3. <kbd>^D</kbd> will clear the current line *not* including whitespace (<kbd>^dg_</kbd> saves trailing space)
4. <kbd>0C</kbd> will clear the current line including whitespace and put you into insert mode
5. <kbd>^C</kbd> will clear the current line *not* including whitespace and put you into insert mode (<kbd>^cg_</kbd> saves trailing space)

<kbd>cc</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> will function as either 4. or 5. if 'autoindent' is off or on respectively.

So use whatever fits the action at hand. I believe that <kbd>0D</kbd> is the fastest to clear the line, but you can map that to something if you wish, to make it even faster.

Comment: @SuperScript `S` is a synonym for `cc`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, @akshay; TYLTK it's up with the very best: http://vi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aa#answer-id-242

Comment: `cc` is nice to use, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Yep.  If there's one thing I'm liking about Vim, it's that the answer to "Can I do that?" is almost always an emphatic **yes**.

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Jumps to the beginning, then deletes through the end of the line.

<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (not Ctrl+D) will jump to the first non-whitespace character, then delete through the end.

<sup>(P.S.  I figured this out just now and wanted to share with any other noobs.  Please let me know if there's a better way.)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Clear the line with one (shifted) key: <kbd>S</kbd>.

This also keeps the indent.

You go into insert mode at the first position after the indent, or at start of line - just what you need to substitute a line - therefore the name `S` - like substitute.

`:help S`

```
["x]S   Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
        insert.  Synonym for "cc" |linewise|.

["x]cc  Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
        insert |linewise|.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
        the indent of the first line.
```

Comment: `S` is a great key.

Answer (score 3):

With Kana's "[vim-textobj-line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3886)" plugin, you can use operations on indented line with `il` (e.g. `dil`), or entire line without the newline, with `al` (e.g. `yal`). The advantage of this approach is subtle: instead of having to think of *both* motions (start, end) for the desired operation, you specify the text-object *directly*: **i**n **l**ine, **a** **l**ine.