# Clear the current line but stay in normal mode

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to delete the contents of the line I'm on without entering insert mode. Right now I have to do `cc` then `Escape` to go back to normal mode, is there a shorter key sequence if I'm in the middle of the line?

Comment: 0D. 0 moves to first column, D clears all to right starting with cursor position. 0 can be changed to ^, if you want to save indent.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate but strongly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3563/1841

Comment: Assuming you mean normal mode, not command, which called with :

Comment: @Dmitry Actually OP is right: normal mode is also called command mode (see [`:h command-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#command-mode)) because that's where you input commands. The mode started with `:` you are referring to is the command line mode [`:h Command-line-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#Command-line-mode)